# How to set "activate" class to bootstrap navbar in Angular 2 while using page anchor navigation?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am creating a single page website using Angular 2 and Bootstrap 4.

I created a navbar component that is always on top of the page and I am using page anchor navigation (#id). Please note that I haven't created a routing module (so far it hasn't been necessary to do this).

The navbar code is below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default fixed-top navbar-inverse navbar-toggleable-md">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Garatéa</a>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseExample" class="navbar-collapse collapse" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#home">Início</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#team">Quem Somos</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Each link corresponds to a section of the single page website, for example, the home component template is:

```
<div id="home" class="text-center home-background">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Bem vindo à <strong><span class="title-text">Garatéa</span></strong></h1>
      <p class="lead">Somos uma inciativa que <strong>aumenta a taxa de sobrevivência</strong> em emergências médicas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is: how can I highlight the link in the navbar that corresponds to the section of the website that I am currently browsing? For example, if I am looking at the team about section, I expect to have an `active` CSS class on the navbar: `<li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">Sobre</a></li>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the srcElement on click of that `<a>` tag as below

```
<a class="nav-link" (click)="clickedLink($event)">Início</a>
<a class="nav-link" (click)="clickedLink($event)">Início</a>
<a class="nav-link" (click)="clickedLink($event)">Início</a>
```

Method will be as

```
clickedLink(e){
let element = e.srcElement;

console.log(e)
for(let i =0; i <element.parentElement.children.length ; i++){
  if(element.parentElement.children[i].classList.contains('active')){
    element.parentElement.children[i].classList.remove('active')
  }
}
element.classList.add('active');
```

}

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/rLgHtdFba3F1B2rTqJe2?p=preview)

Comment: Hi @Aravind, thanks for your great answer! However one more thing that I would like to do is to set the active class to the links not only when I click on them, but also when I scroll my page. For example, the about link (Sobre) should be active whenever I click on it, or if I scroll down to the About component. Do you have any suggestions about the scrolling part?

Comment: I didnt get your point can you elaborate? if this answer is helped mark it and upvote too

Comment: Well, since my website is a single page application, the users can access each of its sections by either scrolling down or clicking the links above (each link takes the user to a section of the website, all sections are in the same page). I would like to highlight the correct section link on the navbar, whether the user clicks on a link or just scrolls down.

Comment: however your menu will be in the same parent `ul`